# aws ec2 describe-instances: how to filter *out* spot instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I can list all my spot instances by issuing the following CLI command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name="instance-lifecycle",Values="spot"
```

But how can I show all my *not* spot instances? None of these work:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name="instance-lifecycle",Values=""
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name="instance-lifecycle",Values="?"
```

(the `instance-lifecycle` is empty / null for non-spot instances, similarly for `spot-instance-request-id`)

Comment: Have your tried the Values="normal" in your CLI query

Comment: That returns an empty response, so it doesn't look like that works.

Comment: Can you confirm if the below syntax worked for your requirement?

Answer (score 5):

AWS CLI and console are not working for filtering instance-lifecycle "normal".

So I've use jq tool instead of '--filter Key=instance-lifecycle,Values=scheduled'

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name="instance-state-code",Values="16" \
| jq '.Reservations[]?.Instances[]? | select(.InstanceLifecycle == null)| .InstanceId' -r
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can do this via the `--query` option.

I've struggled to find good documentation on the option itself but I managed to come across the fact that you can pass filters inside it.

For example these 2 commands will return the same:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "[{\"Name\": \"tag:role\", \"Values\": [\"web\"]}, {\"Name\":\"instance-state-name\", \"Values\": [\"running\"]}]" --query='Reservations[*].Instances[*].[LaunchTime,PrivateIpAddress][]'

aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "[{\"Name\": \"tag:role\", \"Values\": [\"web\"]}]" --query='Reservations[*].Instances[?InstanceStateName=="running"].[LaunchTime,PrivateIpAddress][]'
```

What this also allows us to do is filter items in the instances output which do not have a specified tag (e.g. "Normal" instances do not have a "InstanceLifecycle" attribute so return `null`):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "[{\"Name\": \"tag:role\", \"Values\": [\"web\"]}, {\"Name\":\"instance-state-name\", \"Values\": [\"running\"]}]" --query='Reservations[*].Instances[?!InstanceLifecycle].[LaunchTime,PrivateIpAddress][]'
```

Note `Instances[?!InstanceLifecycle]` in the query.

Comment: is there any other way now to filter out spot instances besides using the query option?

Comment: @D.prd not that I'm aware of. This solution itself wasn't easy to come by and I haven't seen any others.

Hopefully Amazon will make this simpler at some point.

Comment: I had to modify the above a bit to get only spot instances


`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-lifecycle,Values=spot" --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query='Reservations[*].Instances[?InstanceLifecycle].[InstanceId]'`

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Windows Platform you can use the below command to list all instances that are on-demand instance

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,InstanceLifecycle]" --output table --region eu-west-1 | find "None"
```

Similarly, for all spot instance

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,InstanceLifecycle]" --output table --region eu-west-1 | find "spot"
```

On a Linux environment the below might get the results

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, InstanceLifecycle]' --output text |
%{if ($_.split("`t")[1] -match "None") { $_.split("`t")[2]; } }
```

NOTE: I havent tested the Linux environment command as I currently do not have access to Linux

Comment: This does the filtering on the client side, which I'm trying to avoid.